# How to pass all the devise params to entry_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parameters

Rails 4 uses the following function to trust params before allowing them in the database.

```
def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:title_of_work, :size, :price, :media)
end
```

I'm also using the devise gem and I want to allow all this through too but it doesn't work.

For example

```
def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:title_of_work, :size, :price, :media, :current_user)
end
```

or

```
def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:title_of_work, :size, :price, :media, current_user.id)
end
```

How do I pass the user information stored in the devise object through to be put into another called Entry?

Comment: stick a break point int your controller method and examine the params() hash.  That will tell you what you need to permit in your entry_params() method

Comment: yes but what is the syntax, nothing works for me.

Comment: Dump it here and we will parse it for you

Comment: hey thanks, I though I had. I want to pass the current_user from devise as a permitted field. Dumping my params wont show the :current_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all = params.require(:entity).permit(:title_of_work, :size, ...).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
```